# How to compile with clang and mingw-w64?

Tags: c++, exception, clang, mingw-w64, c++20

I'm trying to use clang10 with mingw-w64's libstdc++, since the MSVC headers don't support clang 10. I don't mind not having the new parts of the standard library, I just want to use the new language features.

I have mingw-w64 version 8.1.0 for x86_64 with POSIX threads and SEH exceptions installed and I run clang with a command:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -std=c++20 ...
```

Everything works OK. All the language features that should be implemented in clang 10 work, but when I throw any exception, this happens when I run the program (the program compiles OK):

```
Mingw-w64 runtime failure:
  Unknown pseudo relocation protocol version 65536.
```

I tried installing mingw with SJLJ exceptions and use the `-fsjlj-exceptions` flag in clang, but the program doesn't even compile:

```
C:\Users\egst\AppData\Local\Temp\test-f4a4de.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\Users\egst\AppData\Local\Temp\test-f4a4de.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\Users\egst\AppData\Local\Temp\test-f4a4de.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
```

`clang++ --version` shows `Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`. Maybe there's a version for `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` that I should use instead? Is there any way to make this work at this moment, or should I wait for support from MSVC? Is there maybe any alternative besides MSVC and MinGW?

Comment: mingw-w64 is a port of gcc  . clang is a different compiler.

Comment: @M.M OP's probably talking about using GCC's libstdc++ with Clang.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Exactly. Edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: I'm using GCC & Clang installed from MSYS2, and exceptions work for me. As a bonus, I get a fresh GCC (9.3), and Clang defaults to `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`. I haven't tested exceptions on the vanilla Clang with MSYS2 GCC though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'll try that, thanks. I will edit the question to allow a solution with any relevant alternative to mingw.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've tried, and I can confirm that this works with MSYS2 perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @HolyBlackCat 's sugestion, I tried this with MSYS2 and it works perfectly. I simply installed MSYS2, then from the MSYS bash I installed [this](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-clang) package. It installs everything in in `...\msys2\mingw64`. You get clang 10 (+ gcc 9.3) and all the needed stl headers (still no c++20 headers like `<concepts>` though).